# Как соединить свой сайт с websocket? (lorawan)

Tags: javascript, html5, websocket

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBykW.png)У меня есть сервер lorawan и кнопка с антенной. Когда я нажимаю на кнопку, то на сервер lorawan отправляется пакет данных. [image: Сигнал с кнопки]
В столбце Data показаны пакеты данных. Последняя цифра показывает тип нажатия. (например: 1 - простое, 2 - долгое, 3 - двойное нажатие) Задача: сделать сайт, на который будут отправляться эти данные через websocket. Я взял один бесплатные хостинг, теперь осталось разобраться с кодом. Можете подсказать статью, или написать сами что нужно прописать в коде для получения данных. Вот настройки websocket. Буду очень рад любой помощи в этом деле. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: Ошибка при подключении]
Код таков:

```js
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://5.134.219.10:48080/ws/nodes/FF09E1E2");

ws.onopen = function() { alert("Connection opened...") };
```

Comment: Если речь о показе чего-то на страничке, то с веб-сокетами прекрасно справится JavaScript. Примеры кода можно посмотреть [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket). Также этот сервер lorawan (я не знаком с ним) - должен быть доступен из интернета (если хотите показывать это всем), либо в локальной сети (если хотите наблюдать только у себя на своем компе).

Comment: Добрый день! Спасибо что откликнулись. Да, на эту статью я уже натыкался,  но подключиться не получилось. Смотрите: index.html
  `<html>
<header><title>Да, не красиво, ну и что!?</title></header>
<body>

<p> Добрый день. </p>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>`
script.js 
`let socket = new WebSocket("ws//IP:48080/ws/event");

socket.onopen = function(e) {
  alert("[open] Соединение установлено");
};`

Comment: Я попробовал подключиться к ws://IP:48080/ws/nodes/FF09E1E2. И во вкладке events у меня выдало это {404,"/ws/nodes/FF09E1E2",<<"admin">>,"217.67.185.94"} . В основной теме я приложил фото.

Comment: Также, для удобства я уместил код js там же. (в теме)

Comment: Почти всё, что я сказал раньше, можете забыть. Я попробовал подключиться к /ws/uplink  и у меня это удалось(проверил фунцией socket.onopen) Но на сервере мне выдало это:  json_syntax_error . В общем мне нужен json код, чтобы его отправить на сервер и получить в ответ значение кнопки.

Comment: УРАААА. ПРЛУЧИЛОСЬ . СПАСИБО. Но инфо о кнопке он выводит свержу как javascript. Осталось это вывести в html